# JavaFX KeyEvent for media key is blank (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, ubuntu, javafx, ubuntu-14.04

Having trouble handling media keys in JavaFX (8.0.25) in Ubuntu 14.04. I can't tell any of them apart!

Example: mute button (XF86AudioMute / 121)
event type: KEY_PRESSED
code: UNDEFINED
char: ''
text: ''
code.isMediaKey(): false

I get the same behavior with any of the other media keys, as well any unbound special application keys (dell keyboard with 'back arrow' 'forward arrow' 'home icon' etc)

xev can identify the keys just fine (ex: mute is 121)

How do I distinguish these key events in JavaFX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question with a workaround:

I was not able to do this directly with JavaFX, instead I resorted to rebinding the media key to a function key:
(example for mute button)

1. Unbind existing dconf setting:
Note: this persists automatically
dconf-editor or gsettings
package: org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
key: volume-mute
EX: gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute ''

2. Get keycode:
xev | grep KeyPress -A 5
press desired key
make note of keycode

3. Bind new mapping with xmodmap:
Note: this does not persist automatically in 14.04, even when saved to ~/.Xmodmap
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap (to get current settings)
Edit ~/.Xmodmap and make desired changes
EX: keycode 121 = F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 F11 XF86Switch_VT_11 (mute button is now F11)
Apply: xmodmap ~/xmodmap.conf

4. Persist
option 1: add 'xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap' to a login script
option 2: add 'usermodmap="$HOME/.Xmodmap" to /etc/gdm/Xsession